# Manage non-generic page section in Wagtail

Tags: wagtail

I try to find a solution to handle a non-generic page section on in my Wagtail-based project.

First, this is about some page (assume it presents some project case study) which has 8 sections, 7 of them are 100% generic and reusable. Their fields are described in page model file. This page will be reused 10-100+ times.

Meanwhile, one of those 8 sections completely 70-100% non-generic from page to page. Please look at screenshots below to get the idea:

[image: options of Solution section]

There are 3 unique (for the moment, will be much more in future) options of one section called Solution. I kept in mind StreamField to apply it for this case before I dove into it but it was my mistake. I planned to create one StreamField block per one unique Solution section but, as I found out then, it does not support inline models (they may help me in case of middle and right design layout). I see my case is a bit complex for StreamField feature.

My another possible approach is based on assumption that I can have the common model **project_page.py** which contains 7 generic section and is filled out with unique content for each project, then a sub-model is being created to cover all needs of non-generic Solution section using full power of static 'field-by-field' declared pages. Then this sub-model is being selected from list of sub-models in binds to main Project case study page model. Same time **project_page.html** template has empty **{% block solution %}{% endblock %}** place where sub-model-based template **project_page_(project_name).html** inherits **project_page.py** template and inserts itself to that solution block.

One thing more here that I need access project page via URL kinda **sample.com/work/(project_name_slug)**, after that main 7 generic sections page model, which should use that sub-model content and it shouldn't be accessible alone.

Maybe somebody has any ideas to solve it. Please share.

Comment: Does anybody have an experience with sub-pages to use them as a part of parent page? This may help me as well.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is so simple and based on inheriting generic page model by non-generic. Worked for me.